# Is there a reason to use dd if I don't use any extra parameters?

Tags: dd

I often use `dd` when I for example want to copy an image to a usb drive. I only do `dd if=infile of=/dev/sdb`. Is there any advantage to this over `< infile > /dev/sdb`? And is this the exact same as `pv infile > /dev/sdb`?